# Real Time Chart with Serial port Data in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I want to drawing real time chart in c# with my data that read from serial port Arduino device i didn't know how  can i do this with c#.
i want 2d and 3d chart in my program anyone can help me ?
in my program i read  data from serial port and time of data has been arrived so my chart be have 2 data one of them is info and another is time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using port.dbDataSetTableAdapters;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Factory_Performance
{
    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
        int sfs = 0;
        string filename;
        string line;
        string s;
        string temp="";
        string temp1="";
        Series series = new Series();
        SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort();

        internal delegate void SerialDataReceivedEventHandlerDelegate(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e);
        internal delegate void SerialPinChangedEventHandlerDelegate(object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e);
        private SerialPinChangedEventHandler SerialPinChangedEventHandler1;
        delegate void SetTextCallback(int ReadByte);
        int InputData = 0;


        private int CountData;
        private string StrData;
        double[] Values;
        public FrmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SerialPinChangedEventHandler1 = new SerialPinChangedEventHandler(PinChanged);
            ComPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived_1);
        }

        private double calculate_input(int s2, int s3)
        {


            return double.Parse(s2.ToString() + "/" + s3.ToString());

        }

        private void GetAllIDInDB()
        {
            tblIDTableAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet.TblID);
            CmbID.Items.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < dbDataSet.TblID.Rows.Count; i++)
                CmbID.Items.Add(dbDataSet.TblID.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
        }
        private void GetAllID_DetailsInDB(int ID)
        {
            tblID_DetailsTableAdapter.FillByID(dbDataSet.TblID_Details, ID);
            listreadtxt.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < dbDataSet.TblID_Details.Rows.Count; i++)
                listreadtxt.Items.Add(dbDataSet.TblID_Details.Rows[i]["Value"].ToString());

        }

        private void GetInfoPorts()
        {
            try
            {
                string[] ArrayComPortsNames = null;
                int index = -1;
                string ComPortName = null;
                cboPorts.Items.Clear();
                cboBaudRate.Items.Clear();
                cboStopBits.Items.Clear();
                cboParity.Items.Clear();
                cboHandShaking.Items.Clear();
                //Com Ports
                ArrayComPortsNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                do
                {
                    index += 1;
                    cboPorts.Items.Add(ArrayComPortsNames[index]);


                } while (!((ArrayComPortsNames[index] == ComPortName) || (index == ArrayComPortsNames.GetUpperBound(0))));
                Array.Sort(ArrayComPortsNames);

                if (index == ArrayComPortsNames.GetUpperBound(0))
                {
                    ComPortName = ArrayComPortsNames[0];
                }
                //get first item print in text
                cboPorts.Text = ArrayComPortsNames[0];
                //Baud Rate
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(115200);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(300);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(600);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(1200);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(2400);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(9600);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(14400);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(19200);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(38400);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(57600);
                cboBaudRate.Items.ToString();
                //get first item print in text
                cboBaudRate.Text = cboBaudRate.Items[0].ToString();
                //Data Bits
                cboDataBits.Items.Add(8);
                cboDataBits.Items.Add(7);
                //get the first item print it in the text 
                cboDataBits.Text = cboDataBits.Items[0].ToString();

                //Stop Bits
                cboStopBits.Items.Add("One");
                cboStopBits.Items.Add("OnePointFive");
                cboStopBits.Items.Add("Two");
                //get the first item print in the text
                cboStopBits.Text = cboStopBits.Items[0].ToString();
                //Parity 
                cboParity.Items.Add("None");
                cboParity.Items.Add("Even");
                cboParity.Items.Add("Mark");
                cboParity.Items.Add("Odd");
                cboParity.Items.Add("Space");
                //get the first item print in the text
                cboParity.Text = cboParity.Items[0].ToString();
                //Handshake
                cboHandShaking.Items.Add("XOnXOff");
                cboHandShaking.Items.Add("None");
                cboHandShaking.Items.Add("RequestToSend");
                cboHandShaking.Items.Add("RequestToSendXOnXOff");
                //get the first item print it in the text 
                cboHandShaking.Text = cboHandShaking.Items[0].ToString();


            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("خطا در گرفتن اطلاعات پورت");
            }
        }

        private void port_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {



            InputData = ComPort.ReadByte();


            object firstByte = InputData;

            if (ComPort.IsOpen==true)
            {


                s = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(firstByte));
                temp1 += s;
                lock (firstByte) {    
                if (Convert.ToInt32(firstByte) == 13)
                    {

                    temp = temp1;
                    temp1 = "";
                        ComPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                        ComPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                        LstGetInfo.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>
                    { 
                        if (temp !=null)
                        { 
                    LstGetInfo.Items.Add(temp);


                            if (LstGetInfo.Items.Count >= 100)
                            {


                                    LstGetInfo.Items.Clear();


                            }
                            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append);
                            var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0} {1}", temp, DateTime.Now.ToString("hh mm ss")) +"\r\n");
                            fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                            fs.Close();

                        }
                    }));
                        LstGetInfo.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                {
                                    LstGetInfo.TopIndex = LstGetInfo.Items.Count - 1;
                                }));

                }

                }
            }
        }
        internal void PinChanged(object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Values = new double[CountData];
            for (int i = 0; i < CountData; i++)
                Values[i] = (int)StrData[i];
            Array.Reverse(Values);
            chart1.Titles.Clear();
            chart1.Titles.Add(TxtTitle.Text);
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            series.Points.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < CountData; i++)
                series.Points.AddXY(TxtTitleSeries.Text + " " + i.ToString(), Values[i]);
            chart1.Series.Add(series);

        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void CmbPalette_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Palette = (ChartColorPalette)CmbPalette.SelectedIndex;
        }

        private void CmbChartType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            series.ChartType = (SeriesChartType)CmbChartType.SelectedIndex;

        }

        private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart2.Series.Clear();
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dbDataSet.TblID_Details' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tblID_DetailsTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbDataSet.TblID_Details);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dbDataSet.TblID' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tblIDTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbDataSet.TblID);
            GetInfoPorts(); 
            CmbPalette.SelectedIndex = 1;
            CmbChartType.SelectedIndex = 4;
            CountData = 0;
        }
        private void btnGetSerialPorts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetInfoPorts();
        }
        private void btnPortState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sfs == 1) { 
            try
            {
                if (btnPortState.Text == "ارتباط با دستگاه")
                {
                        temp1 = "";
                        temp = "";
                    btnPortState.Text = "قطع ارتباط با دستگاه";
                    ComPort.PortName = Convert.ToString(cboPorts.Text);
                    ComPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cboBaudRate.Text);
                    ComPort.DataBits = Convert.ToInt16(cboDataBits.Text);
                    ComPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cboStopBits.Text);
                    ComPort.Handshake = (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), cboHandShaking.Text);
                    ComPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cboParity.Text);
                    ComPort.Open();
                    LstGetInfo.Items.Clear();

                }
                else if (btnPortState.Text == "قطع ارتباط با دستگاه")
                {
                    btnPortState.Text = "ارتباط با دستگاه";
                    ComPort.Close();

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                btnPortState.Text = "ارتباط با دستگاه";
                ComPort.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("خطا در انجام عملیات");
            }
        }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("برای ذخیزه فایل محلی را انتخاب کنید");
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            savedata();

        }
     private void savedata()
        {
            try
            {
                if (LstGetInfo.Items.Count < 0) return;
                int ItemCount = int.Parse(listreadtxt.Items[0].ToString());
                int ItemIDCount = 0;
                int ItemID = 0;
                int ItemValue1 = 0, ItemValue2 = 0;
                TblIDTableAdapter tblid = new TblIDTableAdapter();
                TblID_DetailsTableAdapter tblid_details = new TblID_DetailsTableAdapter();
                tblid.DeleteAllID();
                LstGetInfo.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < ItemCount; i++)
                {
                    ItemID = int.Parse(LstGetInfo.Items[0].ToString());
                    LstGetInfo.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                    tblid.Insert(ItemID);
                    if (LstGetInfo.Items.Count > 0)
                    {

                        ItemIDCount = int.Parse(LstGetInfo.Items[0].ToString());
                        LstGetInfo.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                        for (int j = 0; j < ItemIDCount; j += 2)
                        {
                            ItemValue1 = int.Parse(LstGetInfo.Items[0].ToString());
                            LstGetInfo.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                            ItemValue2 = int.Parse(LstGetInfo.Items[0].ToString());
                            LstGetInfo.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                            tblid_details.Insert(ItemID, calculate_input(ItemValue1, ItemValue2));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("در ساخت نمودار مشکلی پیش آمده است");
                try
                {

                    LstGetInfo.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                GetAllIDInDB();
            }
            ShowChart();
        }
        private void CmbID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetAllID_DetailsInDB(int.Parse(CmbID.Text));
            if (listreadtxt.Items.Count > 0)
                ShowChart();
        }

        private void CmbPalette_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Palette = (ChartColorPalette)CmbPalette.SelectedIndex;
        }

        private void CmbChartType_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            series.ChartType = (SeriesChartType)CmbChartType.SelectedIndex;
        }
        private void ShowChart()
        {
            CountData =listreadtxt.Items.Count;
            Values = new double[CountData];
            for (int i = 0; i < CountData; i++)
                Values[i] = double.Parse(listreadtxt.Items[i].ToString());
            chart1.Titles.Clear();
            chart1.Titles.Add(TxtTitle.Text);
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            series.Points.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < CountData; i++)
                series.Points.AddXY(TxtTitleSeries.Text + " " + i.ToString(), Values[i]);
            chart1.Series.Add(series);


        }

        private void button3_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetAllIDInDB();
        }



        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            openFileDialog1.FileName = string.Empty;
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
            listreadtxt.Items.Clear();
                Stream fs = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                listreadtxt.Items.Add(line);


            }

            reader.Close();
            }
        }

        public void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dateTimePicker1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {



                DialogResult result1 = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                string formatvalue =Convert.ToString( dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("  yyyy-MM-dd"));                
                filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName + formatvalue + ".csv";
                if (result1==DialogResult.OK) 
                {
                    sfs = 1;
                }




            }));
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                ComPort.Close();          
            CountData = LstGetInfo.Items.Count;
            Values = new double[CountData];
            for (int i = 0; i < CountData; i++)
                Values[i] = double.Parse(LstGetInfo.Items[i].ToString());
            chart2.Titles.Clear();
            chart2.Titles.Add(TxtTitle.Text);

            series.Points.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < CountData; i++)
                series.Points.AddXY(System.DateTime.Now, Values[i]);
            chart2.Series.Add(series);
            }
            catch
            {
                LstGetInfo.Items.Remove(0);
            }
            finally
            {

                ComPort.Open();

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Also explain 3d-chart!! (Best show an example) - Also: Try to estimate the speed and number of data you receive..

Comment: What happens if you run your code?

Comment: my data is unlimited and i Received 2 data in second

Comment: my code didn't work

Comment: Do you know at which interval your measured points occur? because you are trying to add all the points you read since the last read occurred at the same x-axis value (`Datetime.Now`) (and by the looks of it you do this after you close the serial connection rather than continuously reading and updating the graph, so every single point is added at the same x value)

Comment: actually, from what i can understand in your question you expect two values from the arduino per read : a value and a time at which the value was measured. correct?

Comment: simply put ; if that is the case, we need more code. post a complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in line

```
series.Points.AddXY(System.DateTime.Now, Values[i]);
```

you are adding points with the same X value set to `System.DateTime.Now`. In result you have only one point on axis X.

Comment: that seems to be part of the problem, yes ; but not a solution to it.

Comment: i know this but i need a solution for my problem i write this code for example

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace chart
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string s;
        int InputData = 0;
        private delegate void CanIJust();
        Series series = new Series();
        private List<int> _valuelist;
        private Thread _thread;
        private CanIJust _DoIt;
        private Random _ran;
        private int _interval;
        private List<double> _timelist;
        private List<int> _customValueList;
        SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort();
        int sfs = 0;
        string temp = "";
        string temp1 = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
            chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0;
            _valuelist = new List<int>();
            _ran = new Random();
            _interval = 500;
            tbupdateinterval.Text = "500";
            GoBoy();
            _timelist = new List<double>();
            _customValueList = new List<int>();
        }



        private void GetInfoPorts()
        {
            try
            {
                string[] ArrayComPortsNames = null;
                int index = -1;
                string ComPortName = null;
                cboPorts.Items.Clear();
                cboBaudRate.Items.Clear();
                cboStopBits.Items.Clear();
                cboParity.Items.Clear();
                cboHandShaking.Items.Clear();
                //Com Ports
                ArrayComPortsNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                do
                {
                    index += 1;
                    cboPorts.Items.Add(ArrayComPortsNames[index]);


                } while (!((ArrayComPortsNames[index] == ComPortName) || (index == ArrayComPortsNames.GetUpperBound(0))));
                Array.Sort(ArrayComPortsNames);

                if (index == ArrayComPortsNames.GetUpperBound(0))
                {
                    ComPortName = ArrayComPortsNames[0];
                }
                //get first item print in text
                cboPorts.Text = ArrayComPortsNames[0];
                //Baud Rate
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(115200);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(300);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(600);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(1200);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(2400);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(9600);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(14400);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(19200);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(38400);
                cboBaudRate.Items.Add(57600);
                cboBaudRate.Items.ToString();
                //get first item print in text
                cboBaudRate.Text = cboBaudRate.Items[0].ToString();
                //Data Bits
                cboDataBits.Items.Add(8);
                cboDataBits.Items.Add(7);
                //get the first item print it in the text 
                cboDataBits.Text = cboDataBits.Items[0].ToString();

                //Stop Bits
                cboStopBits.Items.Add("One");
                cboStopBits.Items.Add("OnePointFive");
                cboStopBits.Items.Add("Two");
                //get the first item print in the text
                cboStopBits.Text = cboStopBits.Items[0].ToString();
                //Parity 
                cboParity.Items.Add("None");
                cboParity.Items.Add("Even");
                cboParity.Items.Add("Mark");
                cboParity.Items.Add("Odd");
                cboParity.Items.Add("Space");
                //get the first item print in the text
                cboParity.Text = cboParity.Items[0].ToString();
                //Handshake
                cboHandShaking.Items.Add("XOnXOff");
                cboHandShaking.Items.Add("None");
                cboHandShaking.Items.Add("RequestToSend");
                cboHandShaking.Items.Add("RequestToSendXOnXOff");
                //get the first item print it in the text 
                cboHandShaking.Text = cboHandShaking.Items[0].ToString();


            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("خطا در گرفتن اطلاعات پورت");
            }
        }
        private void GoBoy()
        {
            _DoIt += new CanIJust(AddData);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = now.ToOADate();
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = now.AddSeconds(10).ToOADate();
            _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ComeOnYouThread));
            _thread.Start();

        }
        private void ComeOnYouThread()
        {
            while (true)
                try
                {
                    chart1.Invoke(_DoIt);
                    Thread.Sleep(_interval);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:" + e.ToString());
                }
        }
        private void AddData()
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            InputData = ComPort.ReadByte();


            object firstByte = InputData;

            if (ComPort.IsOpen == true)
            {


                s = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(firstByte));
                temp1 += s;
                lock (firstByte)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(firstByte) == 13)
                    {

                        temp = temp1;
                        temp1 = "";
                        ComPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                        ComPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                        _valuelist.Add(Convert.ToInt32(temp));
                        chart1.ResetAutoValues();
                        if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 0)
                        {
                            while (chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue < now.AddSeconds(-5).ToOADate())
                            {
                                chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = now.AddSeconds(5).ToOADate();
                            }
                        }
                        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(now.ToOADate(), _valuelist[_valuelist.Count - 1]);
                        chart1.Invalidate();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);
            if (_thread != null)
                _thread.Abort();
        }


        private void btn_2D_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn_2D.Enabled = false;
            btn_3D.Enabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
        }

        private void btn_3D_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn_2D.Enabled = true;
            btn_3D.Enabled = false;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
        }

        private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _customValueList.Add(_ran.Next(0, 100));
            _timelist.Add(DateTime.Now.ToOADate());
            updatesecondChart();
        }
        private void updatesecondChart()
        {
            chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(_timelist[_timelist.Count - 1], _customValueList[_customValueList.Count-1]);
            chart2.Invalidate();
        }

        private void btn_serialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_updateInterval_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int interval = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(tbupdateinterval.Text, out interval))
            {
                if (interval > 0)
                    _interval = interval;
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("بازه زمانی باید بیشتر از 0 باشند");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("I nappropriate Data.");
            }
        }

        private void btnGetSerialPorts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetInfoPorts();
        }

        private void btnPortState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (sfs == 1)
            //{
                try
                {
                    if (btnPortState.Text == "ارتباط با دستگاه")
                    {
                        temp1 = "";
                        temp = "";
                        btnPortState.Text = "قطع ارتباط با دستگاه";
                        ComPort.PortName = Convert.ToString(cboPorts.Text);
                        ComPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cboBaudRate.Text);
                        ComPort.DataBits = Convert.ToInt16(cboDataBits.Text);
                        ComPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cboStopBits.Text);
                        ComPort.Handshake = (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), cboHandShaking.Text);
                        ComPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cboParity.Text);
                        ComPort.Open();
                        AddData();

                    }
                    else if (btnPortState.Text == "قطع ارتباط با دستگاه")
                    {
                        btnPortState.Text = "ارتباط با دستگاه";
                        ComPort.Close();

                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    btnPortState.Text = "ارتباط با دستگاه";
                    ComPort.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("خطا در انجام عملیات");
                }
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("برای ذخیزه فایل محلی را انتخاب کنید");
            //}
        //}

        private void CmbPalette_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Palette = (ChartColorPalette)CmbPalette.SelectedIndex;
        }

        private void CmbChartType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             series.ChartType = (SeriesChartType)CmbChartType.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
}
```